# Why does this code leak instance of Sample class?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

Any idea on why this code leaks (over-retains) instances of `Sample` class after `[startSampling:action:]` method is called on them? Profiler shows positive retain count after sampling is complete (i.e. `sample()` block returns `YES`). ARC is obviously enabled.

```
@implementation Sample

- (void)startSampling:(BOOL (^)(Sample *sender))sample action:(void (^)(Sample *sender))action {
    __block void (^next)(Sample *sender) = nil;

    void (^block)(Sample *sender) = ^(Sample *sender) {
        if (sample(sender)) {
            action(sender);
        } else {
            [self performBlock:next afterDelay:self.duration / 100.0];
        }
    };

    next = block;

    [self performBlock:block afterDelay:self.duration / 100.0];
}

@end
```

Comment: Since you are not assigning `next` from inside the block, you should replace `__block` with `__weak` (there is a hard reference to the block from the `block` variable). This should fix the problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `__block` is necessary there, otherwise the `block` block will hold a copy of `next` variable instead of reference to it. In other words, without the `__block` quantifier, updates to the `next` variable are never picked up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `next` is captured by the block. Blocks retain any captured variables of object pointer type when copied (actually, since it's a variable of block pointer type, it is copied instead of retained). Under ARC, `__block` variables are retained too. `next` is set to point to the block, so the block has a strong reference to itself. That's why you have a retain cycle.

To fix it, you simply have to make `next` a weak reference:

```
__block __weak void (^next)(Sample *sender) = nil;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a block in that method.  The block is essentially a `struct` with a field for each of the externally-defined variables used by the block, plus some extra stuff like a pointer to the code to be run for the block:

```
struct TheBlock {
    void (*function)(TheBlock *);
    // other bookkeeping fields

    __strong TheBlock *next;
    __strong OtherBlockType *sample;
    __strong OtherBlockType *action;
    __strong Sample *self;    
};
```

When you do `next = block;`, you're setting that `next` field to point to the struct containing it.  So the block retains itself, which is a retain cycle, preventing the block from being released.  And the block also retains `self`, preventing the `Sample` instance from being released.

One way to fix it is to set `next` to `nil` when you're done with it:

```
void (^block)(Sample *sender) = ^(Sample *sender) {
    if (sample(sender)) {
        action(sender);
        next = nil;
    } else {
        [self performBlock:next afterDelay:self.duration / 100.0];
    }
};
```

That will break the retain cycle when the block is no longer needed, allowing the block and the `Sample` instance to be deallocated.

Comment: with `__block` variables it's slightly more complicated